# Next episode preview song in Darker Than Black

Tags: music, darker-than-black

For the life of me, I cannot find the song that plays at the end of each episode of Darker Than Black (both seasons, subbed+dubbed) during the next episode preview.

Could someone either provide the name or some way to find it?

Here's a clip of what I'm looking for - https://clyp.it/pxwptiqg.

Comment: Have you tried looking through the soundtrack? Also googling lyrics? Perhaps music recognition apps?

Comment: There are no lyrics and I spent 4 hours searching every site with soundtrack listings. I'm currently trying a music recognition app, but no luck so far.

Comment: I've added an audio clip for reference. The audio recognition app had as much luck as I've had so far.

Comment: Are you sure those are official previews? I don't think I remember hearing that, but maybe I always skipped them. Make sure it's not a dub's own thing, coz then you might need to ask the dub crew about the  track.

Comment: @Hakase they're definitely official. Both versions are voiced by the correct voice actors. They play at the end of each episode, after the credits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is "Water Forest", track #18 from [the season 1 OST](http://vgmdb.net/album/19094). Here is a 30-second extract from the beginning of the track: https://clyp.it/i5pumfdi

Comment: You are my new favorite person. I could never find this - even after checking the OST. Guess I was looking in all the wrong places ^_^ Thank you! I can sleep now!

Answer (score -1):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2bAPhU9YSIE
I believe, perhaps. I only did some mild research, and you know it's in the title of the vid.

Comment: That's the ending theme song, not the next episode preview song. Thanks, though.